# How to tell scripts editor that I want to attach this script to this spreadsheet using the Id I'm currently editing the spreadsheet in

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I have a spreadsheet open and use the menu to open the script editor, the script comes up attached to the wrong Google ID.  I am in a Chrome browser session that very clearly shows the correct icon in the upper right corner, but the script editor doesn't recognize the owner of the spreadsheet I've called the editor from

Comment: I may have resolved this by dumping the Chrome history; but probably started right up again since to login in here after cleaning, I've now told this copy of Chrome, managed under gsuite, that a non chrome email is bing used to access sites here.  So I need to try to remember to see which ID google is using when working on scripts and sites.  Is there a browser add on that will monitor tabs to make sure that when logged in somewhere they are all the same ID?
I

Comment: What I do is to use one Chrome profile for each of the accounts that I use to create scripts. Anyway, All the relevant details about the question should be included in the question body as well a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].